# Puppeteer throwing error when running non-headless

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to visit a webpage and view all the network requests that fire but I've found that an error is thrown when running in non-headless mode and I can't figure out the cause of this error. No amount of Googling has turned up an answer so far. Here's the error:

```
/Users/myusername/dev/puppeteer-test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:226
                error: new Errors_js_1.ProtocolError(),
                       ^

ProtocolError: Protocol error (Page.createIsolatedWorld): No frame for given id found
    at /Users/myusername/dev/puppeteer-test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:226:24
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at CDPSession.send (/Users/myusername/dev/puppeteer-test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:222:16)
    at /Users/myusername/dev/puppeteer-test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:290:37
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at FrameManager._ensureIsolatedWorld (/Users/myusername/dev/puppeteer-test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:290:14)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async FrameManager.initialize (/Users/myusername/dev/puppeteer-test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:102:13)
    at async FrameManager._onAttachedToTarget (/Users/myusername/dev/puppeteer-test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:185:9) {
  originalMessage: 'No frame for given id found'
}
```

This is a dumbed down sample of my project code that throws this error:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = 'https://jpstyle.us/';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 250
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  let foundRequest = false;
  let request;

  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  page.on('request', (interceptedRequest) => {
    if (interceptedRequest.url().includes('googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads')) {
      foundRequest = true;
      request = interceptedRequest;
    }

    interceptedRequest.continue();
  });

  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
  await browser.close();

  console.log(`Google Ads Remarketing was ${foundRequest ? 'found' : 'not found'}`);

  if (foundRequest) {
    console.log(request);
  }
})();
```

If you change the value of `headless` to `true` in the launch options object that is passed when launching puppeteer then this error goes away and everything runs as expected. For the purposes of this project I can't run in headless mode, so I need to figure out why this error is happening.

Any help or direction is appreciated!

Comment: Have you had any luck?  I'm running into this as well.

Comment: @Josh1billion Looks like there's a [PR that fixes this](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/7848).